# How to calculate the Rise speed of a travelling wave?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

As you can see in this wikipedia animation

[image]

Phase velocity (red) and group velocity (green) are described, and both show different "speed" in the Propagation direction but what about the transverse direction speed?

How do I calculate the rise speed of a cycle in transversal direction ?

(Look at the extremes of the picture the blue pixel going up and down, this is the vertical up-down speed what I want to calculate)

For example in a very simple wave like this

y(x,t) = A* sin(kx - w t), should I calculate derivative of y having x=constant?

What about in general? How to calculate the Rise speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you know the phase velocity $\omega$, you know that along the $x$ axis the red dot is described by $x(t) = \omega t$. Then you just apply the chain rule. The value of $y(x,t)$ at the red dot is a function of time $y(x(t),t)$. So 
$$ \frac{d}{dt}y(x(t),t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}y(x(t),t) \cdot \frac{d}{dt}x(t) + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} y(x(t),t) $$
which we more succinctly write as
$$ \omega \partial_x y + \partial_t y $$

Comment: To clarify, the position/velocity of a point on the wave can be modelled as SHM (simple harmonic motion), which is what Willie Wong is effectively doing.

Comment: How can I compute the solution to a simple case, for example in wolfram alpha ? I think I would need to specify k=constant, w=constant

Comment: k does not matter.

Comment: This is the way in wolfram alpha to do that w*D(A*Sin(k*x - w*t),x)+D(A*Sin(k*x - w*t),t) 

Comment: you said k, don't mind, but this is the result I get, A (k-1) w cos(t w-k x) so, if k=1, then rise speed = 0 ? mmmm something is wrong

Comment: For a monochromatic traveling wave, the phase and group velocities are the same. So in fact the rise speed is 0 (in the animation you linked to, a monochromatic wave will have the red dot and the green dot coincide, and note that the green dot does not have transversal motion). To see anything non-trivial you need to have a wave with components of multiple frequencies, and you need a dispersion relation so that the different frequencies travel at different speeds. 

Comment: @Willie Wong, so that animation (I though could help) finally confuse it all.. To understand what I want to ask, perhaps we shouldn't look at the red dot, I want to know the up-down axis speed of the wave, watching at the left side of the animation, you can see "first" left most pixel going up and down, this is the vertical speed I want to really calculate, and this speed is not zero even for a simple monochromatic traveling wave, thanks Willie

Comment: Then you are just looking at the vertical position change fixing the $x$-coordinate, which means that it is exactly given by just the partial derivative in the time-direction, $\partial_t$.